# How to replicate Postman API request with binary file in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I want to replicate this postman api request to Cypress

[Postman API request w/ binary file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct6Vp.png)

I tried this in cypress but i can't achieve the 200 response code

```
cy.fixture(objData.fixtureFilePath, 'binary').then((file) => {
            return cy.request({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: `${url}`,
                form: true,
                body: file,
    
            })
        })
```

I just want to ask if how can I replicate the above postman api request to cypress.